# prepare data for machine learning

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, linear-regression

I'm working on deep learning using linear regression. I have a real day that I collected from the hospital (patient arrival time, triage, exam time, and length of stay), but the data are not clean and it has high and very low values. For example, the mean waiting time in the dataset is 28 minutes and the standard deviation of the waiting time in the dataset is 75  minutes.

What is this called in machine learning? is it unbalance data? and how can I overcome this problem? Are there any techniques in data science that can help to make these data well prepare for machine learning?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your different features (i.e. waiting time, triage, etc.) may have grossly different scales (as you said, one feature may have a mean of 28 and a standard deviation of 75, while a different one might have a different scale entirely). You are correct in assuming that this may make training more difficult.

One very common solution is called normalization: you recalculate each feature assuming that it is distributed according to a mean 0 and a standard deviation of 1. To apply this to a dataset is really simple: all you have to do is, for each feature in each individual entry, subtract the mean (which will make 0 the new mean) and divide the result by the standard deviation (which will make 1 the new standard deviation). This procedure is common enough that it is already implemented in a vectorized way in most machine learning or statistics frameworks.

While this mitigates the problem in shallow models (like a linear regression, as is your case), models with multiple layers may still suffer from this in the intermediary layers. In that case, a related technique called batch normalization is often applied after each layer.